# Как привязать один блок табов к другому блоку табов

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здраствуйте!
Подскажите, как привязать один блок табов к другому блоку табов,
т.е. при смене в верхнем блоке табов происходит смена в нижнем блоке табов?

В каком направлении двигаться?
Один блок табов к другому блоку табов:

http://szsi.com.ua/page/test/

Вот пример:
При выборе в верхнем табе соответствующая вкладка должна открытся снизу:
бронза сверху - бронза снизу
и т.п.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**html:**

```
<form id="slider" data-min="1" data-max="3">
  <div class="tab_img">
    <span class="prev" data-type="3" onclick="ChangeType($(this).data('type'));">назад</span>
    <img class="img" src="type_1.png"  height="50" width = "50"/>
    <span class="next" data-type="2" onclick="ChangeType($(this).data('type'));">вперёд</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs_info">
    <div class="type_1 select" data-type="1" onclick="ChangeType($(this).data('type'));">type_1</div>
    <div class="type_2" data-type="2" onclick="ChangeType($(this).data('type'));">type_2</div>
    <div class="type_3" data-type="3" onclick="ChangeType($(this).data('type'));">type_3</div>        
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="type" value="1"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Подробнее"/>
</form>
```

**js(jquery):**

```
ChangeType = function(numb) {
  $('.img').attr('src', 'type_'+numb.toString());

  $('.tabs_info').children().removeClass('select');
  $('.type_'+numb.toString()).addClass('select');

  $('input[name="type"]').val(numb);

  var sl_max = $('#slider').data('max'),
      sl_min = $('#slider').data('min');
  if($('.prev').data('type')==sl_min) {
     $('.prev').data('type',sl_max); 
  } else { $('.prev').data('type',($('.prev').data('type')-1)) }

  if($('.next').data('type')==sl_max) {
     $('.next').data('type',sl_min); 
  } else { $('.next').data('type',($('.next').data('type')+1)) }
   }
```

[вот](http://jsfiddle.net/er4mdc1w/)